# How to insert default value in unknown column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a function that INSERT INTO a table some data. I **do not know** how much columns the table has (let it be **N**).

My func gets a list of **N-1** params and then

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES( *N-1 params* )
```

The last N-th column is a standart **ID** column, which i want to set DEFAULT (ID column has the default value = "max" and is auto incremented)

**The main problem:** due to the fact that i do not know names of the columns i am working with, i can't manually enter data into the database.

How to insert a row of data, if I don't know the number of columns, but I know that I have 1 less than it should be and the last column is auto incremented / has the default value?

Comment: Is ID column auto incremented?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Yeah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the order of the N-1 params is exactly the same as the order of the columns in the definition of the table (the `CREATE` stamenet), then there is no need to enumerate the names of the columns in the `INSERT` statement.

Add, 1 more `NULL` value to the list for the `ID` column (at the end of the list if, as you say it is defined last):

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(param1, param2, ..., paramN-1, NULL)
```

By passing NULL for the `ID`, it will be incremented since it is defined as `AUTOINCREMENT`.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7f48ad4d0f3208832959abf231a0fc4c).